# Как конвертировать String в Int из массива powershell

Tags: powershell

Как конвертировать String в Int из массива

```
$date1 = [int]$file[8]+[int]$file[40]+[int]$file[72]+[int]$file[104]
```

Таким способом получается 0

Comment: Думаю, стоит привести соответствующие значения массива

Comment: Проверил, это вполне рабочий код.